# Child project not finding parent with relativePath

Tags: maven, docker, build, dependencies, gitlab-ci

I've create a project parent used to manage dependencies and version in child projects, see the  pom.xml

```
<groupId>myCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Than, i created a child project, that inherited from the parent, see the pom.xml

```
<parent>
<groupId>myCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>filrstChild</artifactId>
<name>filrst Child</name>
```

Note the two project are in the same folder

- group :

  - parent
  - firstChild

PS :

the child projects are already exists before parent, so the architecture is not from scratch, that why i didn't use the standard way to created parent & modules

with `gitlab-ci` i'm trying to build the firstChild, after building parent

So, parent build correctly, but firstChild is not building

this is my gitlab-ci on firstChild

```
image: appinair/jdk11-maven

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - target/

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
  artifacts:
      paths:
        - target/
        - .m2/repository/
```

And this is the error that i got after building firstChild

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for myCompany:firstChild:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact myCompany:parent:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project myCompany:firstChild:[unknown-version] (/builds/compiere-ws/firstChild/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for myCompany:firstChild:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact myCompany:parent:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

So, any idea ?

PS:

Note that the firstChild build correctly in my local server or with jenkins, it's not building only with gitlab-ci

Comment: Use the group location as parent and not a sibling directory as parent. That is not logic... and your required order is not possible neither does it make sense...a parent does not contain any code so the parent is the first one which is being built afterwards the childs will be built.